# How to listen to changes in Firestore with ESP8266?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, arduino, esp8266

How do i listen to data changes in Firebase Cloud Firestore with ESP8266? So far i have managed to connect ESP8266 with firestore to read and post data to Firestore using the REST API, but instead of constantly reading data from Firestore, I want to listen to an event when the data changes in Firestore.

In short, I want to have a stream open  where i am listening for changes in Firestore.

This can be done with Firebase Real-time database, but i haven't found examples for Firestore.

Here is an example of what i am trying to do, but with real-time database: https://github.com/mobizt/Firebase-ESP8266/blob/master/examples/Stream/Stream.ino

Comment: Can i see the steps u followed to store data from ESP8266 to Firestore? So far i can only see that data can be stored in Realtime database but cant find anything on Firestore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was asking around on some forums, and i found out that sadly this is not possible :(

> The Cloud Firestore supports the REST API unless stream like feature are not available due to poor performance and Firebase team decided to remove this feature.

> The only possible method that suitable for no Firebase SDK installation is the RPC (gRPC) which is not currently available in embedded device.
> The other problem is database secret can't use in the Cloud Firestore, the auth or custom token is required and need the SSL/TLS library for key encryption and signing. This can be done in ESP32 with mbed TLS which can't do this in ESP8266 with BearSSL.

> Then Cloud Firestore with realtime feature (using gRPC) is not possible in ESP8266.

- From a issue on github@Firebase-ESP8266: https://github.com/mobizt/Firebase-ESP8266/issues/126

The workaround can be using a webserver and/or Firebase Functions, which sadly was the thing I was trying to avoid.